# Сделать редирект на внутреннюю страницу только для мобильной версии сайта и чтобы можно было зайти на главную страницу?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, .htaccess

Всем доброго здоровья! Подскажите, пожалуйста не хватает знаний и опыта. Тема изложена в вопросе. Я написал такой скрипт

```js
var a = window.location.pathname;
function redirect() {
      if ((a === "/") && ( screen.width < 768 )) {
         window.location = "/kupit-eloxal/cepi-na-metraj/eloxal-gold-ekonom-585-proby"; 
      };                                                              
  };
redirect();
```

работает хорошо, но теперь нельзя зайти на главную страницу сайта, идет перенаправление. Помогите решить задачу. Спасибо!

Comment: сделайте условие, что если screen.width >768, то с внутренней страницы делаем редирект, например на страницу с ошибкой 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    function redirect() {
     var a = window.innerWidth;
     var b = document.referrer;
            if ((b == "") && (a < 768)) {
               window.location = "/kupit-eloxal/cepi-na-metraj/eloxal-gold-ekonom-585-proby"; 
            };                                                              
      };
    redirect();
```

Спасибо Вам большое за варианты ответов!) Я нашёл такое решение

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

    alert("Вы используете мобильное устройство (телефон или планшет).")

} else alert("Вы используете ПК.")
```

или через mobile-detect.js